# he not be stopped

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

> He kept her gait down because it was very important that he not be stopped.

This sentence is from Cold Iron by Miles Cameron, a medieval fantasy book. I find this sentence strange. Could we rephrase it as:

> ... him not being stopped was very important.

or

> ... him being not stopped was very important.

or, maybe:

> ... it was very important him not being stopped

And is it an idiomatic sentence that the writer has written here, or is it just there to impart an archaic quality to the story?

Answer (score 6):

"He [not] be stopped" is using the the present subjunctive of the verb 'to be'. This form is identical to the bare infinitive (and imperative) of the verb (in this case 'be') in all forms. The main use of the English present subjunctive is in *that* clauses expressing a circumstance that is desired, demanded, recommended, necessary, etc. It is more likely to be found in more formal writing and in speech by educated speakers.

[English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

Comment: I don't think this is a subjunctive form, as there is no hypothetical situation here. There is a future situation whose outcome is not yet known.

Comment: The subjunctive mood in English is used to form sentences that express not just  hypothetical states of affairs, but also those that are wished for, or tentatively assumed. These include statements that express opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire.

Comment: I would say that "Let there be light" is in the imperative, not the subjunctive. it is a command (from God to the universe).

Comment: Yes, i read it. Are you saying that  "Let there be light" expresses a wish or tentative assumption? Or that it indicates "opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire"? Are you saying tha tit is both imperative and subjunctive? Indeed just what are you saying about this phrase? It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that it's idiomatic or archaic.

Remove the negative, and it's a pretty uncontroversial sentence:

> It was very important that he be stopped.

It may seem slightly bit odd because of the passive voice, but this construction isn't unusual in English:

> They shouldn't be worried.
>
> Those weren't meant to be eaten!
>
> You shouldn't be sitting there.

Your first rephrasing is OK, though the word ordering would seem a bit odd to a native speaker.

The second is a bit bizarre, though I've heard similar constructions (usually indicating that the speaker doesn't know the a word, such as an antonym for *stopped*, and is indicating that while emphasizing the condition they want to express).

The third is very unusual, having the pronoun *it* at the start of the sentence and the antecedent *him not being stopped* without the word *that* in between, though with a comma between *important* and *him* you get a fairly common construction.

Comment: Thank you. Does my second rephrasing imply that he's stopped at the moment and him being allowed to move again is important, whereas the first one implies he's moving and it's important for him to keep moving and not be stopped?

Comment: @TapaniHirvi No, the meanings are the same and the implications are not really different. The second sentence treats *not stopped* as a single unit (like there are two states: *stopped* and *not-stopped*). The only implication I (a native speaker) would draw from the second sentence and not the first is that you don't know a good word to indicate the *not-stopped* state and are doing some circumlocution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could I also say, "... that he not be stopped was very important."?

Comment: @TapaniHirvi You could definitely phrase it that way. As a complete sentence it would be very slightly odd (it's not very common for English sentences to be so thoroughly in the passive voice), but I don't think it would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A more usual was to express this meaning would be "it was very important that no one stop him." The quoted passage is in the passive voice, because it is emphasizing the possible act of stopping the character, and the character's efforts to avoid it. The person who might do the stopping, who would be the subject of the verb "stop" in an active construction is not important to the author, and so the author has avoided it by a passive construction. This is a case where a passive construction is better than an active one, in my view.

The agent could be indicated with a by clause as:

> It was very important that he not be stopped by anyone.

However, this doesn't really add anything to the meaning.